# Combining two variables to create custom x-ticks in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime

I want to create a plot where the x-ticks should look like the following

```
 2004 01 03       2004 01 10     2004 01 17         ...
Square is 4.0   Square is 81.0   Square is 256.0    ...
```

The dates are stored in a numpy array of datetime objects and the secondary values (in this case [0, 1, 4, ...]) are stored in a numpy array of the same size. My code is below -

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.subplot(111)

time = np.zeros(30, dtype=object)
data1 = np.zeros(30)
data2 = np.zeros(30)

for i in range(30):
    time[i] = dt.datetime(2004,1,1,0,0,0) \
              + dt.timedelta(days=1)*i
    data1[i] = i
    data2[i] = 2*i

ax.plot(time, data1)

Mtick = mdt.DayLocator(bymonthday=None, interval=7)
mtick = mdt.DayLocator(bymonthday=range(1,32))
fmt   = mdt.DateFormatter('%Y %m %d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(Mtick)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mtick)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

plt.show()
```

How can I customize/format the ticks to include the secondary values from the `data2` variable?

Edit:
The tick values should have the same index for both `time` and `data2` variables. 
Also, in this example the `time` variable is evenly-spaced, but in my real data this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1).clf()
ax  = plt.subplot(111)

data1 = np.arange(30)
time = dt.datetime(2004,1,1,0,0,0) + dt.timedelta(days=1)*data1
data2 = data1*data1

ax.plot(time, data1)
major = slice(2,None,7)
ax.set_xticks(time, minor=True)
ax.set_xticks(time[major])
ax.set_xticklabels([t.strftime('%Y %m %d') + '\nSquare is ' + str(d2) for (t,d2) in zip(time,data2)][major])
```

Comment: This is useful but unfortunately my real data is not evenly spaced in time, so using slice is a bit inaccurate as I don't know a-priori which indices will map to which time.

Comment: Your problem is not well defined then since you have no guarantee that the tick location corresponds to an existing data point thus you can attach a `square = data2` value to it...

Comment: Fair enough, I needed to be more clear. It is guaranteed that every `time` value has a mappable `data2` value. In my actual code, `data2` is a function of `time`. So if there is a time tick at say 2004/01/03 , and if I can access the value corresponding to this tick, I can pass it to a function to get the corresponding `data2` value.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem with my solution?